# MySQL via PHP - Minus the older record first

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my example tb_product_order

```
[pkey]|  prcode  |  totalorder 
------|----------|-------------
   1  |  HAP002  |           6
   2  |  HAP001  |           2
   3  |  HAP002  |           4
   4  |  HAP004  |           8
```

And I want to update the table by subtracting the `totalorder` value of `HAP002` by `8`

```
[pkey]|  prcode  |  totalorder 
------|----------|-------------
   1  |  HAP002  |           0  --> Subtract this first by the max value (6)
   2  |  HAP001  |           2
   3  |  HAP002  |           2  --> Then subtract this value by the rest value (2)
   4  |  HAP004  |           8
```

But, if the subtraction value < `6`, just subtract the first (oldest) record.

What query should i type down?

Comment: what you are already tried?

Comment: Not yet, i just want to get the best and most efficient way.

Comment: Please share what you have tried. And do you want to update your table or want a select query?

Comment: i thinks need to more clear your question. what is your expected result?

Comment: Your logic isn't clear.  Can you elaborate on the rules you used to arrive at the output?

Comment: This DB structure is strange. What is `HAP002` and why it is split across 2 rows? If you subtract `8` from row 1 you should get `-2`, and row 3 should be `-4`.